# How can I install and use Python (with Kivy) in android studio?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am a fan of Python and I would like to develop android apps using Kivy, I could just use the default Pyhton IDLE but while I was searching in youtube for kivy tutorials I realise that one guy was using android studio **not** with Java but with Python (and kivy)!

Well after some research in the web nobody knows nothing about it and here I am asking this: **1)How can I write android apps using android studio with Python** or simply **How this guy did this?**

For those who want to know, here is the kivy tutorial that runs Python inside android studio!: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDRa5RZx-X0&list=PLZocUikpczs_E9lPp4uzA8c8203sW-4Ux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The person who made the tutorial is using PyCharm, not Android studio.

PyCharm is the python version of Intellij (both developed by JetBrains), on which Android Studio is largely based, hence they look so much alike.

You cannot do python for android in Android Studio.

Comment: Oops my mistake then, it was really so similar! Thank you!

Comment: But kivy is crosss platform right? They have announced that it can be used for developing android application. Infact i tried but i was not successfull .

Comment: i am still finding the way how i can use python for android.

Comment: Hi everyone, this questions seems to be my interest. I want to create an android app for analysis purpose. I have python scripts but to make an application I have to use android studio (AS). So I just want to connect my python code with AS and I thought kivy would be a better option. So, am I making sense or my strategy is not correct.

Comment: @Rhea android studio doesn't cater for python/kivy

Comment: Thanks I got my answer. Firstly, we have to make layout with kv and then build app with buildozer. No need to use Android Studio.

Comment: Can we install Android Studio and Kivy together in a device? Will it cause any problem?